# Python sh: merge results and pipe

Tags: python, sh

How to use the sh module to accomplish [this process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133386/how-to-merge-and-pipe-results-from-two-different-commands-to-single-command) in python?

```
{ cat wordlist.txt ; ls ~/folder/* ; } | wc -l
```

Thanks.

Comment: as you are dealing with code and not image , add your code here !

Comment: @Kasra What do you mean? The unix code is there. Of course, there's no python code, because I don't know how to write it.

Comment: Do you know how to use the `sh` module at all? Are you having trouble with the pipe, or the `{ ... }` construct, or the pathname pattern "~/folder/*"?

Comment: @chepner Yes, I've used `sh` before. I thought the title should make clear that I'm having trouble with the pipe. The example is just a silly example that I've cribbed from a thread that I've found while trying to look this up. I linked to it just to give credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) and a shared [pipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pipe):

```
>>> import os
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> rfd, wfd = os.pipe()
>>> p1 = Popen(['cat', 'some/file'], stdout=wfd)
>>> p2 = Popen(['ls', 'some/path'], stdout=wfd)
>>> os.close(wfd)
>>> p3 = Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=rfd, stdout=PIPE)
>>> print(p3.communicate()[0].decode())
512

>>> os.close(rfd)
```

**UPDATE**:

Not sure whether this is the right way to do things with `sh`, but this seems to work:

```
>>> import os, io, sh
>>> stream = io.BytesIO()
>>> sh.cat('some/file', _out=stream)
>>> sh.ls('some/folder', _out=stream)
>>> stream.seek(0)
>>> sh.wc('-l', _in=stream)
512
```

Comment: Thanks. So the `sh` module cannot accomplish this, then?

Comment: @bongbang. TBH, I overlooked the `sh` requirement, and I just used what was in the standard library. I don't know anything about `sh`, but I may have a look at it tomorrow and update my answer if I can come up with anything.

Comment: @bongbang. I added an `sh`-style solution to my answer.